# Postgres Multi-Tenant setup for production and tests

Tags: postgresql, unit-testing, database-schema, multi-tenant, rds

I am being asked to extend our production/QA database to include an additional schema reserved for testing. My gut keeps telling me this will lead to no good.

The reasoning I've been given is to avoid spinning up an additional RDS instance. Doing so will cut cost and increase efficiency. I proposed running these test on a local instance, or even a micro EC2 instance. Both were shot down due to the complexity and what I felt was other nonsense.

Before I push back, I am wondering if others may have done this with some success. My experience in testing databases is that the environment should mimic one another as much as possible and that each environment should be isolated.

My Questions are:

- Is a multi-tenant schema the way to go for this? Or is there another shared schema method?
- Has it been heard of to run a multi-tenant schema to support both production and testing interaction?

  - If so, where might I look for inspiration, examples or how-tos?
- What are some of the benefits/pitfalls of taking on this approach?

Comment: Is your production database a multi-tenant database? Or are you using *multi-tenant* to describe the result of adding a schema to a database for testing? (Adding a schema for testing isn't what *multi-tenant* means.)

Comment: Or are you using multi-tenant to describe the result of adding a schema to a database for testing? Yes.  Adding a schema for testing isn't what multi-tenant means. - I'm aware, just didn't know how best to describe it so it would make sense to others.